# issue with authentication in teams bot: how to keep a tab forcibly open?

Tags: authentication, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have developed a bot based on Virtual Assistant Solution Accelerator beta 0.3.
The bot is consumed through Teams, and all in azure.
We are using other services through the bot: office365 and Yammer. The user authenticate through OAuthPrompt as per Virtual assistant code.
Until recently, everything was fine. But we discovered on Tuesday morning that we have an issue for users not already logged in.

In the process of authentication, when clicking on the login button in the oauthprompt card, it opens a new tab, connect the user and show magic code. But now, this tab is closing right after displaying the code, preventing the user to copying it into teams.

If we reopen the tab right after, the code is here and working.
We tested with chrome, Firefox and edge, same result. But on mobile the tab stays open. We tested both through teams app et teams web app.

My question now: is there a way for me to keep a tab open when it's open through a card in teams (action type is openUrl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1553), specifically in that your action type is `openUrl` when it should be `Signin`, now.

Were you using the middleware in order to get it to work initially? The middleware would look something like:

```cs
// hook up onSend pipeline
turnContext.OnSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, nextSend) =>
{
    foreach (var activity in activities)
    {
        if (activity.ChannelId != "msteams") continue;
        if (activity.Attachments == null) continue;
        if (!activity.Attachments.Any()) continue;
        if (activity.Attachments[0].ContentType != "application/vnd.microsoft.card.signin") continue;
        if (!(activity.Attachments[0].Content is SigninCard card)) continue;
        if (!(card.Buttons is CardAction[] buttons)) continue;
        if (!buttons.Any()) continue;

        // Modify button type to openUrl as signIn is not working in teams
        buttons[0].Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl;
    }

    // run full pipeline
    return await nextSend().ConfigureAwait(false);
});
```

There was an update recently that made it so you no longer need the middleware. Instead, follow these steps:

1. Download the newest sample
2. Create your Teams Bot in the App Studio Manifest Editor
3. Under Domains and Permissions, ensure that `token.botframework.com` has been added as a valid domain.

   - Optionally, enable Web app Single Sign-On with your appId and `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`
4. Click Install and start talking to your bot

If you've done substantial work to your bot and don't want to use a fresh sample, update all of your packages to 4.4.4 and I believe you can just add this to the top of your `OnTurnAsync()`:

```cs
if (turnContext?.Activity?.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "msteams")
    await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
else
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
```

If that doesn't work, you can try using this:

```cs
protected override async Task OnUnrecognizedActivityTypeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext?.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
        new Activity()
        {
            Type = ActivityTypesEx.InvokeResponse,
            Value = null
        });
        await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The middleware made it so the cards in Teams use `Action.OpenUrl` (which no longer works) instead of `Action.Signin` (which is what every other channel uses).

---

Per @SylvainBarbot, you may also need to update your packages, as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/1456)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was not able to find related bug on github. I'm gonna try it tomorrow and come back.

Comment: @SylvainBarbot Any luck?

Comment: Sorry, I was out of the country the last few day, I'm currently testing it

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with your solution, but I also had to update some nuget packages related to this issue https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/1456

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll add that into my answer to make sure others find it.